# Countdowntimer with value from API

Tags: java, android

Hello i have an android app that displays alerts from an api, and i pretend to add a countdown timer to it. It will use a value from the api. How can I achieve this? The api value comes as a string like this example: "10m 25s"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to combine the [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) and substring those values to a plain time.

For example. You take out the 10m as a variable and the 10s to another and then do an adition:

```
String test = "10m 25s";
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(test.subSequence(0, test.indexOf("m")).toString());
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(test.subSequence(test.indexOf("m")+1, test.indexOf("s")).toString().trim());
    int totalMillis = (minutes*60000) + (seconds*1000);
```

And then use CountDownTimer like:

```
new CountDownTimer(totalMillis, 1000) {
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
 }.start();
```

Comment: And how can I format the time after creating the CountDownTimer so the TextView will display the time counting down with the format that comes in the api? Basically converting millis to x mins and y secs

Answer (score 0):

```
private CountDownTimer batteryCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(yourTick, TotalTime) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //handled when the tick expires.

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
           //handle onFinish of ur timer here
        }

    };
// make your time in integer and put it inside Total time.
```